h2db: can I use parameterized WITH clauses (CTEs) in subqueries
I'm using h2db 2.2.224 as Test-DB in Spring Boot 3.2.5, running a JPA native query.
I have a WITH clause (CTE) that uses a query parameter. This WITH clause does not work in a subquery against h2db. It does work against PROD-DB Oracle 19c
I need someone to confirm that the example below contains some simple error I don't see, or that parameterized WITH clauses in subqueries are not supported by h2db.
I can confirm that 'unparameterized' WITH clauses can be used in subqueries inside a view with h2db (bottom of example).
Example
Consider this parameterized query, that still works as expected against h2db:
WITH CTE_FOO AS (
    SELECT f.ID,
           f.BAR_ID,
    FROM FOO f
    WHERE f.LOCATION_ID IN ?1
),
CTE_BAR AS (
    SELECT b.ID,
           b.DESCIPTION
    FROM BAR b
    WHERE b.LOCATION_ID IN ?1
)
SELECT cf.ID           AS FOO_ID,
       cb.DESCRIPTION  AS BAR_DESCRIPTION
FROM CTE_FOO cf
LEFT JOIN CTE_BAR cb ON cf.BAR_ID = cb.ID

The result set is like
FOO_ID BAR_DESCRIPTION
====== ===============
1      babble
2      gibber
....

Now, if I change the very last line, introducing a subselect
WITH CTE_FOO AS (
    SELECT f.ID,
           f.BAR_ID,
    FROM FOO f
    WHERE f.LOCATION_ID IN ?1
),
CTE_BAR AS (
    SELECT b.ID,
           b.DESCIPTION
    FROM BAR b
    WHERE b.LOCATION_ID IN ?1
)
SELECT cf.ID           AS FOO_ID,
       cb.DESCRIPTION  AS BAR_DESCRIPTION
FROM CTE_FOO cf
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM CTE_BAR ) cb ON cf.BAR_ID = cb.ID

The result set is missing the joined fields, which comes unexpected
FOO_ID BAR_DESCRIPTION
====== ===============
1      NULL
2      NULL
...

However, using unparameterized WITH clauses in subquery inside a view works with h2db.
When putting the below code into schema.sql and querying the view, the result set contains the joined fields again.
CREATE VIEW VW_FOO_BAR AS
WITH CTE_FOO AS (
    SELECT f.ID,
           f.BAR_ID,
    FROM FOO f
),
CTE_BAR AS (
    SELECT b.ID,
           b.DESCIPTION
    FROM BAR b
)
SELECT cf.ID           AS FOO_ID,
       cb.DESCRIPTION  AS BAR_DESCRIPTION
FROM CTE_FOO cf
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM CTE_BAR ) cb ON cf.BAR_ID = cb.ID

So it seems the problem only occurs when using parameter + WITH clause + subquery.

There is a known regression in H2 2.1.214–2.2.224 with JDBC parameters in CTEs. Older versions aren't affected. This regression and many other bugs with CTEs were fixed, but new version with these fixes is not released yet.

Thanks @EvgenijRyazanov. I can see issue #3554, that it was merged on 2024-01-29, and that it's is not on the changelog. But if this comment on #3554 is true, I really wonder why the very first query in my example is actually working ... it shouldn't

H2 2.3.230 with CTE fixes was released: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/releases/tag/version-2.3.230

Upgrading H2 to version 2.3.230 fixed the issues with parameterized WITHs/CTEs.
A big 'thank you' to the H2 maintainers.
